# rake db:create:all FATAL : password authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rake

I am trying to follow this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) tutorial. Now I am in the step, where you create the database with rake db:create:all, but I got this error message :

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user aldila
```

I made the user aldila through pgAdmin, by right-clicking the login role and add user aldila with password.

So, here is my database.yml :

```
development:
   adapter: postgresql
   host: localhost
   encoding: unicode
   database: my_app_development
   pool: 5
   username: aldila
   password: *mypass*

test:
   adapter: postgresql
   host: localhost
   encoding: unicode
   database: my_app_test
   pool: 5
   username: aldila
   password: *mypass*

production:
   adapter: postgresql
   host: localhost
   encoding: unicode
   database: my_app_production
   pool: 5
   username: aldila
   password: *mypass*
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Maybe there is something's wrong with the installing of PostreSQL, because if I type 
psql --version on my command, this is what I got :

```
'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But I have no idea what went wrong. I install it from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/) and pick download the installer from EnterpriseDB for all supported versions.

I know there are already similar questions like this, but I follow [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817301/rake-dbcreate-fails-authentication-problem-with-postgresql-8-4) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439276/rails-deploying-to-heroku-many-problems), but I still get the same error message. I would be really appreciated, if anyone could help. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `devise`? Maybe you forgot to add `password_confirmation`.

Comment: No, I don't. Do you mean to create the login role for database? I used pgAdmin and add login role through pgAdmin, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your postgresSQL password didn't match your database.rb's password.. it depends on what environment you are using..